# Nonsequential Counting for Database IDs

Tags: database, math, counting

Say you're YouTube and you're designing an ID system for referring to YouTube videos in the URL. You wouldn't want these to be sequential as someone could easily hop around IDs and find a bunch of unlisted videos.  They could also upload 2 videos in short succession to profile how many videos are being uploaded.

The obvious solution is to use a random number as the video ID, but as the number of videos grows, your chance of a collision goes up.

So say you have a 4 byte ID, the max combinations for ID is around 4 Billion. Is there any efficient way to walk this list of numbers such that you hit all the numbers but in a nonsequential order?

Comment: I had a professor once talk about using relative prime numbers to achieve this.
Say your number of combinations (n) is 10. You pick a number relatively prime to n (usually n-1 is relatively prime to n). So 9. 
Then you count 0 < i < 10 and multiply (i * 9) % 10.  Therefore your IDs would be: 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. 
This is a little better but still not perfect!

Comment: Take a look at Maximum length feedback shift register random number generators https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence

Comment: I'll look at it. thanks!

Comment: You could also just shuffle the bits so the numbers appear to jump around but are in fact totally predictable. e.g. make a new ID by taking [bit2 bit32 bit7 bit29 bit1 ...] from a sequential count.